# Solve $(y^{\prime\prime\prime})^2 + (y^{\prime\prime})^2 = 1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve $(y^{\prime\prime\prime})^2 + (y^{\prime\prime})^2 = 1$

Let $p = y^{\prime\prime}$, so the differential equation now is $p^2 + (p^\prime)^2 = 1$.

But then what I can do? I'm stuck because I don't know what to do with $(p^\prime)^2$.

Comment: Have a sharp look and you see $p(x) = \sin(x + c)$ with $c \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**:
$$p^2 + (p')^2 = 1$$
$$ p' = \pm \sqrt {1-p^2}$$
It's separable.
$$\int  \dfrac {dp}{\sqrt {1-p^2}} = \pm \int dx  $$